# displaying divs in 3 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display the data I fetch from my data base in divs arranged in three columns so I did this:

```
    <table id="produse">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="fluid">First Column</th>
            <th class="fixed">Fixed Column</th>
            <th class="fluid">Third Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the javaScript file I did this:

```
function getRow(aparat){

    var row ='<td>'+'<div id="prod">'+
        '<div>'+ '<img src='+aparat.imagine+' width="150" height="80" />' +'</div>'+
        '<div>'+ aparat.nume + '</div>' +                                                    //functia care le aranjeaza
        '<div>'+ aparat.pret +'&nbsplei' + '</div>'+
        '<div>'+'<button type = "button" id = "comanda">'+'Comanda'+'</button>'+'</div>'
        + '</div>'+'</td>';

        return row;
}
```

But it's displaying my products in only one line, any solutions?

Comment: I assume you meant in only one *column* (not row).Your getRow has only one `<td>` instead of 3.

Comment: add this in jsonlint so things are clear

Comment: P.S. You are better off using any form of template system instead of string concatenation. Then you can author easily visible HTML and replace markers within it.

Comment: Is this something like your looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/n4vp7g2p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use display:flex or display:inline-block,but dont use tables for this.tables are bad for layouts unless necessary dont consider using them

check the following code snippets

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  column-1
  </div>
<div>
  column-2
  </div>
<div>
  column-3
  </div>
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  }

.container div{
  margin:5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div>col1</div>
  
            <div>col2</div>
  
            <div>col3</div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps